# Finding the min and max of inputs

Tags: input, python-3.x, max, min

```
poi = float(input("Price of item?"))
if poi <= poi:
    lowest_price = poi
if poi >= poi:
    largest_price = poi
```

trying to find the min and max price of inputs by the user
help

Comment: You do realize you are comparing a variable ``poi`` with itself? Is there something missing from your code?

Answer (score 1):

Python has `max` and `min` built-in functions that find the largest value of a list/set of numbers.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min